# How can I tell my Win10 PC to connect to my bluetooth headphones?

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, bluetooth

I've paired some headphones to my PC. I use these headphones for both my phone and my PC. I will frequently come home with my headphones connected to my phone and want to switch them to my PC.

Currently the only way to do this is to turn off my phone bluetooth and restart my headphones. Is there a way to explicitly tell my PC to connect to my headphones?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. The headphones need to be restarted to initialize a connection to a different device than before. It could've been done differently, but obviously the headphone manufacturer didn't see your setup (which is not that untypical - I have the same "problem").

Answer (score -1):

Kindly refer to this documentation to add your Bluetooth headphones. Make sure your Bluetooth device is turned on and ready to pair

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows-10/getstarted-connect-to-bluetooth-devices